# Setting linux time

Tags: date

```
$ date 042612492005
$ hwclock -w
```

The code above shows how to set the system time, but how's the timestamp string generated in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is exactly?  Is it... how is the timestamp (042612492005) generated?

Answer (score 5):

The `date` format is:

```
MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]
```

So your above example can be read as:

```
12:49:00 04-26-2005
```

---

By the way, that first line sets the *system time* while the second line sets the *hardware clock*. See [this explanation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html).

Answer (score 3):

More the likely, you type it in. In `man date` you can see it take the format `[MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]`

So the above would read 12:49 PM April 26, 2005

Right now , in Texas it is 041122292011 (10:29 PM April 11, 2011)

Answer (score 0):

On linux, the timestamp is generated by the time() function.

```
$ man 2 time
TIME(2)                    Linux Programmer's Manual                   TIME(2)

NAME
       time - get time in seconds

SYNOPSIS
       #include 

       time_t time(time_t *t);

DESCRIPTION
       time()  returns  the  time  since  the  Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1,
       1970), measured in seconds.
```